# IOS Tabs Title without icons white space on the top

Tags: ios, xamarin, tabs, xamarin.forms

I a have page with tabs, in the tabs i only want text, in android the text is centered both vertically and horizontally, without any white spaces, but in the ios version there is a white space on the top of the text, because there isnt icons.
How can i remove the white space on the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom renderer for that:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabBarRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabBarRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            if (TabBar?.Items == null)
                return;

            // Go through our elements and change them
            var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
            if (tabs != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
                    UpdateTabBarItem(TabBar.Items[i]);
            }

            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }

        private void UpdateTabBarItem(UITabBarItem item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // Set the font for the title.
            item.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Your-Font", 10) }, UIControlState.Normal);
            item.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Your-Font", 10) }, UIControlState.Selected);

            // Moves the titles up just a bit.
            item.TitlePositionAdjustment = new UIOffset(0, -2);
        }
    }
}
```

The `TitlePositionAdjustment` is what you're looking for. You can also use this to change the font size if needed using the `SetTitleTextAttributes` method.

Comment: Is working, but i cant give a line break, i want text and then a date below the text, but if i give a System.Environment.NewLine before the date, the date disappears.
I am doing like this in the PCL:

Title = Text+System.Environment.NewLine+date;

Comment: Another thing, if i update the page with new data, the text position  changes to the original position( position without the custom render).

Comment: Apple doesn't give you access to the underlying label to change its numberOfLines property, and since UITabBarItem doesn't inherit from UIView, you can't traverse its view hierarchy searching for it. So multiline is not possible.

Comment: And about the second question, can you help?

Comment: I dont recognize that behavior. Do you have any code to show what youre doing to trigger that?

Comment: I do Children.Clear() , to clear the tabs, and then i call a method to create the new tabs.

Comment: That makes sense. The code I provided only triggers when the ViewAppears. Your code alters the view, but it doesn't re-appear so this code isn't hit the second time around. You could try moving my code to a different method such as ElementChanged or ElementPropertyChanged but that might give some unexpected behavior.